# Which Crayon Shinchan episode has Shinchan and Himawari playing a board game?

Tags: crayon-shin-chan

In *Crayon Shinchan*, there is an episode in which Shinchan and his sister, Himawari, play a board game. I remember Himawari uses big dice to play by flipping herself. In the end, Shinchan loses, and then he plays again with Shiro, his dog.

I want to know the season number and if possible, the episode number.

I can’t find proper organised listing of episodes anywhere like Wikipedia, anime list, fandom wiki, etc. In Wikipedia, half of the episode names are only in Japanese (which I don’t know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an organized list at [wikipedia: List of Crayon Shin-chan episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Crayon_Shin-chan_episodes)

Judging by the mention of the big dice I assume you are looking for episode SPECIAL 16c (japanese episode numbering) with the title of

"Hey, This Game... Is True To Life!"
すごろく勝負で盛り上がるゾ (Sugo ro ku shōbu de moriagaru zo)